# Remaining space in heroku database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

is there a way to find the remaining space in the (shared) heroku database? Doesn't matter whether this is done via commandline or from within the app, I'd just like to know how "big" my DB is.

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`pg:info`](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#database_status) from the command line:

```
$ heroku pg:info
Plan         Ika
State        available for 1 wk
Data size    2.56GB in 102 tables # <--------------------
PG version   9.0.4
Born         2011-03-03 16:01 PST
```

And then look at the "Data Size" value.